# Sticky position bottom for Bootstrap column

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

I'm trying to make a column stick to the viewport when I have scrolled a certain distance. I'm using the new CSS property `position: sticky;` and it works to a certain degree. My problem lies where the column latches on and stays on the viewport. Currently it attaches to the screen as soon as the browser's navigation bar makes contact with the top of the sticky column, but what I want is for it to get fixed when I've scrolled down to the end of the column.

Does anybody know if I can accomplish this by using `position: sticky;`? If it doesn't work, please recommend another way that I can use to achieve the same result.

I've tried the following but none of them worked:

```
position: sticky; top: 0; (This is the original one that I currently am using)
position: sticky; top: 20; (This makes the sticky function malfunction)
position: sticky; bottom: 0; (Same here)
position: sticky; bottom: -100; (Same here)
```

I am using Bootstrap and Wordpress.

Comment: This sounds like you would need JS to apply a class upon scrolling a certain length.  Would also encourage you to review `position:sticky` support as it isn't fully supported yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky